# Node js readline как прочитать все строки

Tags: javascript, node.js

Есть такая задача

Идут входные данные

```
Строка 1
Строка 2
Строка 3
... и тд.
```

Это все не одна строка. Так как прочитать все строки?

Пример ввода-вывода на JS:

```js
const readline = require('readline');
const rl = readline.createInterface(process.stdin, process.stdout);

rl.on('line', (line) => {
    // Введенная строка в переменной line, тут можно написать решение
    console.log(String(result));
    rl.close();
    return;
}).on('close', () => process.exit(0));
```

дальше мне нужно обработать строки к примеру

`line.split("\n");`

но я получаю только первую строку, если убрать `rl.close()` то в функцию так же попадает первая строка. Я не могу понять как мне записать в переменную или массив все строки.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может быть причина в `rl.close();`

так работает как надо

```
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});


rl.on('line', line => {
    console.log(line);
}).on('close', () => {
     console.log('exit'); 
     process.exit(0);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const readline = require('readline').createInterface(process.stdin, process.stdout);
var arr = [];
readline.on('line', (line) => {
    arr.push(line);
}).on('close', () => {
    console.log(arr);
    process.exit(0)});
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]