# Как прочитать несколько строк с помощью модуля readline?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Есть такой код:

```
const readline = require('readline').createInterface(process.stdin, process.stdout);
readline.on('line', (line) => {
    console.log(line)  
    readline.close();
}).on('close', () => process.exit(0));
```

С помощью него я мог прочитать одну строку, каким образом мне прочитать несколько строк?

Comment: Организовать цикл, например

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Node js readline как прочитать все строки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1165944/node-js-readline-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8)

Answer (score 0):

Пушим строки в массив, выводим массив при нажатии Ctrl+C:

```
const readline = require('readline').createInterface(process.stdin, process.stdout);
var arr = [];
readline.on('line', (line) => {
arr.push(line);
}).on('close', () => {
console.log(arr);
process.exit(0)});
```